How may I calculate columns in TeX?
In this example I can define tables with various column widths, from 1 col up to 20 cols. The calculation of the column width is done by \ifnum\columns=1 \csize=0.91\hsize\fi The value "0.91" and others are not calculated in TeX.
The question is: How may I calculate those values in TeX, to keep the section %calculation shorter and better?
Change the number of columns, to get a better impression. columns=5 %number of columns
    %TeX-File
        \TeX
        \input plipsum
        \parindent=0pt
        \hoffset-0in
        \hsize=6.5in%from plain.tex
        \vsize=8.9in%from plain.tex
        \raggedright
        \newcount\columns
        \newcount\column
        \column=1
        \newcount\limit
        \limit=20
        \newdimen\csize
        %defining tables
        \columns=5%number of columns
        \def\ault{Error}
%calculation
        \ifnum\columns=1 \csize=0.91\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=2  \csize=0.500\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=3  \csize=0.330\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=4  \csize=0.250\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=5  \csize=0.200\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=6  \csize=0.160\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=7  \csize=0.140\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=8  \csize=0.125\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=9  \csize=0.111\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=10 \csize=0.100\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=11 \csize=0.090\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=12 \csize=0.083\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=13 \csize=0.076\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=14 \csize=0.071\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=15 \csize=0.066\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=16 \csize=0.062\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=17 \csize=0.058\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=18 \csize=0.055\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=19 \csize=0.052\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns=20 \csize=0.050\hsize\fi
        \ifnum\columns>\limit \csize=0.5\hsize\fi
%end of calculation

        \def\c#1{\vtop{\hsize=\csize #1\vskip\baselineskip}\advance\column by 1 \ifnum\column>\columns \ault\else \fi }
        \def\tablehead{{\bf Table} \vskip\baselineskip
        \hbox{\c{Column \the\column}\c{Column \the\column}\c{Column \the\column}\c{Column \the\column}\c{Column \the\column}\c{Column \the\column}\c{Column \the\column}}\hrule\vskip\baselineskip }
        
        \vskip4\baselineskip
        \tablehead
        \hbox{\c{\lipsum1}\c{\lipsum1}\c{\lipsum1}\c{\lipsum1}\c{\lipsum1}\c{\lipsum1}}
        \bye


it may not be the best idea to redefine \c. if the content of you document changes later, you may need the original meaning. best would be to pick a new name.

why .91 for one column? not full width? @wipet's answer could be further simplified to just the middle of the three lines he showed if it were not for that specific setting that doesn't correspond to any calculation.

@David Carlisle@cfr
Yesterday it wouldn't work with full width, today it does. (???)

You can do this:
\ifnum\columns=1 \csize=0.91\hsize \else
    \csize=\hsize \divide\csize by\columns
\fi


+1 another trick for the bag!
